# Запятая после НУ

Tags: пунктуация

"Ну, а по мне она — красавица." Пунктуация верна?

Answer (score 5):

Запятая после НУ не нужна, так как здесь НУ - частица. Ср.: Ну, начнём, пожалуй. (НУ - междометие). Интонационное тире возможно, хотя после личных местоимений оно обычно не ставится.

Answer (score 0):

После "ну" запятая не нужна. Не оправданна в данном случае.